# How to mark/highlight input in Angular?

Tags: angular-material

I'm using matInput. What I want is that the content in matInput is marked/highlighted so that if I press any key the text gets deleted. For example you double click a word in the search bar here in stackoverflow. How can I archieve that?

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [(value)]="test">
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Angular 8, you can use `@ViewChild` decorator to get a reference to your `input` element. Then you select the input value within the `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook. In order to link the `input` element with `@ViewChild`, you can use a template reference variable (e.g. `#food`).

Please have a look at the following [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-knqxxj?file=src/app/input-overview-example.ts)

> Please note that using `setTimeout` inside `ngAfterViewInit` prevents you from getting an `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`.